# Readymade restful text-storing web service solution

Tags: web-services, rest

I want to build a simple client app for filtering and redirection of requests to simple web services. The platform is Linux, the interface is command line, the data is plain-text quotes, the primary commands will be as follows:

```
pull quotes <service> <filter>
export quotes <filter> <file>
import quotes <filter> <file>
push quotes <service> <filter>
```

I need a web service to serve as a source of plain-text data with simple RESTful interface like:

```
http://www.iheartquotes.com/api/v1/random?source=starwars
```

But with more capabilities - i need ability to search and filter through url/http-request thoroughly, at least like:

```
http://www.someservice.com/api/v1/quote?filter=churchill+war&max=25&order=most_popular
```

And get plain-text as a result. Add/remove capability would be very handy too.

Please, direct me:

**(1) Are there readymade text storage web services with good ~restful interface (like above)?**

**(2) If not, is there a good framework in C++ or python?**

I`ve tried:

(1) Wikia API - I would have to write a good web crawler to get something useful from there, which is not the purpose.

(2) MoinMoin wiki - I deployed it on VM, yet I found that it generates web page content dynamically and doesn`t expose necessary restful api.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there is one.

After long search, i found it - [snipp.io](http://snipp.io)

That doesn't make me stop wanting to make my own, however.